# how to create tabbed structure with arrows pointing right

Tags: html, navigation, css

I would like to reproduce the image below in HTML and CSS.

One option is to use images to do it, and another option is to use [CSS triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) after the tab element such that:

```
<div class="tab"></div><div class="arrow"></div>
```

and then position them. But is there another way to do this where I can get that arrow effect just contained in the css for the tab in one div such that:

```
<div class="tab"></div>
```

Is fully sufficient without having a separate arrow element

+1 if you include a JSFiddle.

[image: tab structure]

Answer (score 1):

I've found the simplest and quickest way is just to use a sprite sheet for these. Adding :after and separate images for :before gets unwieldy very fast.

e.g.[image]

```
header.content nav ul {
    width:552px;
    height:33px;
    background:url("/assets/images/layout/main-nav-background.png") no-repeat;
    background-position:0 -99px;
    float:left;
    list-style: none;   
}

header.content nav.page2 ul {
    background-position: 0 -66px;
}
header.content nav.page3 ul {
    background-position: 0 -33px;
}
header.content nav.page4 ul {
    background-position: 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing it this way anymore.